# Inject generic class through interface

Tags: c#, spring, generics, dependency-injection

How can I inject a generic class through an interface via Spring?

I have a generic interface like this:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<in TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

and an other interface that implements this:

```
public interface IEntity1Repository : IGenericRepository<Entity1>
```

And in my service I use that interface

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private readonly IEntity1Repository _repo;

    public Service1(IEntity1Repository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void Create(Entity1 entity)
    {
        _repo.Create(entity);
    }

    public void Update(Entity1 entity)
    {
        _repo.Update(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(Entity1 entity)
    {
        _repo.Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

I have made a generic class for the generic repository like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    public GenericRepository(TDbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    public TDbContext Db { get; set; }

    public async Task<int> Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        return await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        return await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to inject this class directly into the Service1 with spring like this:

```
<object id="MyDbContext" type="springTest.Test.MyDbContext, springTest" singleton="false" />
<object id="Repository" type="springTest.Test.Repositories.GenericRepository, springTest" singleton="false">
  <constructor-arg ref="MyDbContext" />
</object>

<!-- Services -->
<object id="Service1" type="springTest.Test.Services.Service1, springTest" singleton="false">
  <constructor-arg ref="Repository" />
</object>
<object id="Service2" type="springTest.Test.Services.Service2, springTest" singleton="false">
  <constructor-arg ref="Repository" />
</object>
```

When doing this I get this error: `{"Could not load type 'springTest.Test.Repositories.GenericRepository' from assembly 'springTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"springTest.Test.Repositories.GenericRepository"}`

Is it possible to archive this without creating an empty class that inherits from GenericRepository?

*Project can be downloaded here: [Dropbox download link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qwve9mpo58z3uh/springTest.zip?dl=0), just remember to click "include nuget packages".*

Comment: Why not make the `Service` class depend on `IGenericRepository<Entity1>` directly?

Comment: Don't know why I didn't do that :P . But it still gives the same error

Comment: There is a special syntax for generic types. Take a look at this reference: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html

Comment: Also, unless you need late binding without the need for recompilation, I recommend you use code instead of XML to configure your dependencies. Or even better, to drop the container altogether and use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)

Comment: Thanks @yacoub-massad. Section **5.2.6. Object creation of generic types** explains it. I have it working now :D